# disable Property debugging in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, debugging

I know I can do the following to prevent debugger from entering into Subroutine

```
<DebuggerHiddenAttribute()> _
Private Sub OnTick()
    ...
End Sub
```

Is there a way to do similar thing for a property that looks like this ?

```
Public Property Naziv() As String
    Get
        Return _naziv
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _naziv = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the attribute above the getter and setter:

```
Public Property Naziv() As String
    <DebuggerHidden()> _
    Get
        Return _naziv
    End Get
    <DebuggerHidden()> _
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _naziv = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Also (as this code shows), don’t write out the `Attribut` part of the class name. The convention is that an attribute class `XAttribute` is addressed simply as `X`.